# Lines appear volumetrics

Tags: volumetrics

I am using a Volume scatter node to get a foggy effect, but I get these lines showing up on the floor.[image: the lines I get]

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the density in the volume nodes and the number of render samples until the lines and noise disappear.

Comment: I did that yet I still got the same lines